# Dataloader import field as current datetime now

Tags: data-loader

Is it possible to run a data loader import and set one of the fields being updated to the current date time of `Now()`? What is the best way to accomplish this? I was thinking of creating a temp workflow rule that checks a flag that I set in the data loader update and it runs a field update to system now() on the field I want to set, but that seems like an over kill. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Why not set the default value of the custom date time field to `Now()`? Are you having any standard fields that doesn't support it? Or do you have updates as well in the import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to dynamically set the date on DataLoader as System.NOW().

With that in mind, you can go with:

1. your approach (*Workflow/Apex code to identify records which you inserted/updated from DataLoader and set the value of that field*)
2. [arut](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/55578/arut)'s suggestion on the comments (*set the default value for the DateTime field you created as System.NOW(), that way you don't need to add any workflow rule*).

Best regards!